# Error in json encoding and decoding in oAuth API - PHP

Tags: php, json, oauth

I have created a oauth api in php using this example

```
http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo#OAuth_Consumer
```

And in the consumer page i am passing the params as json encoded string.

```
$key = '35345345345vertrtertert'; // fill with your public key 
$secret = 'h rtyrtyr767567567567'; // fill with your secret key
$url = "www.server.com/serverurl.php"; 

$options = array('consumer_key' => $key, 'consumer_secret' => $secret);
OAuthStore::instance("2Leg", $options);

$method = "POST";
$params = array(
           'radius' => '50',
           'latitude'=>'13.35',
           'longitude'=>'17.35'
     );
$params = json_encode($params);
```

And in the server page(ie serverurl.php) am printing the request using

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

And i decoded the string using json decode, but am getting this value as

```
    Array
(
    [radius] => 50
    [latitude] => 13_35
    [longitude] => 17_35
)
```

The `.` is replaced with `_` in latitude and longitude 
How i can manage this

Comment: If it's consistently doing that, just do a `str_replace()`. It's a hacky solution, but it will work.

Comment: But i dont think that is the good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that somewhere along the line in your encoding/decoding process the value is trying to be parsed a a number of something. If you truly want to work with these values as numbers, you shouldn;t set themn in your array as strings.  Try this

```
$params = array(
    'radius' => 50,
    'latitude'=> 13.35,
    'longitude'=> 17.35
);
```

Note that I have removed the quotes around the numbers so they will be treated as numbers in the encoding process.

Comment: If i remove the quotes, foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value)
{
  $array_val = $key;
}
$decode_val= json_decode($array_val,true);
print_r($decode_val); this code print nothing

Comment: @Warrior What value do you get for `var_dump($params)` after json_encode is performed?

Comment: string(48) "{"radius":50,"latitude":13.35,"longitude":17.35}"

Comment: And is that string intact in the raw $_POST variable in the receiving script? It might help to show the script you are posting to.

Comment: In the receiving script am getting Array
(
    [{"radius":50,"latitude":13_35,"longitude":17_35}] => 
)

Comment: You might want to show the could that actually does the posting in your question.

Comment: @Warrior You show up to the point where you do json_encode, but not where the actual post is being made.

Comment: Before sending the secret key, api key and uri to the server, am encoding the params